# Does having my blog on a different server impact SEO

Tags: seo, webserver

Does having our WordPress blog on 1 server and our Umbraco site on another server but both using the same domain name have any impact on SEO?

Comment: To clarify, is WordPress on a subdomain? Are you using a proxy pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the back end server makes no difference to SEO. Since the blog and the rest of the site are accessible from the same domain name, to all intents and purposes they're one site. It doesn't matter how the content is provided under the domain name.